# Detection of heads in a crowded image using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing, matlab-figure

I'm currently doing a project in "Crowd count estimation" using MATLAB. For that project, I need to find the number of heads in a crowded image (taken using aerial camera). I'm currently using circular hough transform to detect heads in the image.

Head size varies with altitude. So, I have coded in such a way that it accepts (image,Min_head_size,Max_head_size) as parameters. Head size will be taken as radius of circles (Circular hough transform) and circles of that radius will be detected. I've set the threshold as (pi*radius).

With the above approach, I can't detect all the heads. Also lots of false positives are there. Can I proceed in this way? Is there any other solution to count heads precisely?

```
    function Crowd_counter(img,r1,r2)

    img1 = imread(img);                       %read the image
    img=im2bw(img1,graythresh(img1));         %convert into binary
    imgBW = edge(img);                        %'canny' edge detection
    count=0;
    FDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;    %for face detection
    BB = step(FDetect,img1);                   %bounding box for face detect

    for i=r1:r2
        [ydetect,xdetect,Accumulator] = houghcircle(imgBW,i,(i*pi)); %circular hough
        y{count+1}=ydetect;                     %storing y co-ordinates
        x{count+1}=xdetect;                     %storing x co-ordinates
        count=count+1;
        i=i+1;
    end

    disp(count);
    figure;
    imshow(img1);                          %for visualizing detected heads
    hold on;
    crowd=0;
    for j=1:count
        crowd=crowd+length(x{j});          %for counting detected heads
        plot(x{j},y{j},'.','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');
        j=j+1;
    end

    disp('Number of heads:');
    disp(crowd);
    disp('Number of faces:');
    disp(size(BB,1));
    disp('Total');
    disp(crowd+size(BB,1));
```

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOwwb.jpg)

[Output from Crowd_counter('51.jpg',3,7)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5che.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this seems like a decent approach. I haven't experimented with this but from your output image it seems like a lot of edges have been misclassified as heads. My first thought was to use a Hessian matrix like the one used in subsequent steps of [HARRIS corner detector](http://aishack.in/tutorials/harris-corner-detector/) could help eliminate some of these. This should take car of some of the false positives. Figuring out how to find the false negatives will take a bit more effort i guess. Again i would like to emphasize that i have not tried this myself and go down this path only if you feel that the logic makes sense to you.